# FullCalendar error while putting event start time in start options

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

I am implementing the fullCalendar for my application. This is my code to populate the events in the calendar:-

```js
var weekdays = [1, 5]; /*Monday, Friday*/

scheduleObj = {
  '1': [{
      'title': 'Test Title A',
      'start_time': '14:00:00',
      'end_time': '14:30:00'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Test Title B',
      'start_time': '15:00:00',
      'end_time': '15:30:00'
    }
  ],
  '5': [{
      'title': 'Test Title C',
      'start_time': '14:00:00',
      'end_time': '14:30:00'
    },
    {
      'title': 'Test Title D',
      'start_time': '15:00:00',
      'end_time': '15:30:00'
    }
  ]
};

/*specific date which will not have any event*/
var offDayDates = ['2019-07-29', '2019-10-07', '2020-05-04'];

for (loop = start.getTime(); loop <= end.getTime(); loop = loop + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
  test_date = new Date(loop);
  var month = (test_date.getMonth() + 1);
  var day = (test_date.getDate());
  var year = (test_date.getFullYear());

  if (day < 10) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }
  if (month < 10) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  /*formatting dates for comparing with the 'offDayDates' array*/
  var formattedDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  /*storing every day in an array except some specific dates mentioned*/
  if ((weekdays.indexOf(test_date.getDay()) > -1) && (offDayDates.indexOf(formattedDate) == -1)) {
    for (var w = 0; w < scheduleObj[test_date.getDay()].length; w++) {
      // iterate through each events of the day ie. each events of scheduleObj[1] //
      eventsData.push({
        title: scheduleObj[test_date.getDay()][w].title,
        start: test_date,
        color: '#43BADE'
      });
    }
    scheduleDayDates.push(formattedDate);
  }
}
```

Kidnly observe this section of the code where I am pushing info to the eventsData array.

```
eventsData.push({
  title   : scheduleObj[test_date.getDay()][w].title,
  start   : test_date,
  color   : '#43BADE'
});
```

This one works absolutely fine. Buit when I try to put the time, I get deprecated error:-

```
eventsData.push({
  title   : scheduleObj[test_date.getDay()][w].title,
  start   : test_date + 'T' + scheduleObj[test_date.getDay()][w].start_time,
  color   : '#43BADE'
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what _exactly_ does the error message say? If I had to guess I'd say you're probably giving it a date string which isn't recognised, so fullCalendar/momentJS/the JS engine is having to guess a bit. Check https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/moment for details of valid date strings). Also instead of string manipulation like this, have you considered using momentJS's functions...they're very powerful and reliable for manipulating and formatting dates - it could eliminate a lot of manual errors.

Comment: P.S. it would be a lot easier to help you if we could actually run your code. I made a runnable snippet but there are some undefined variables such as `start` and `end` which makes it crash - I assume this doesn't happen in your real version. Can you supply some sample values for those so that we can execute the code? If we can see the actual info being put into `eventsData` it will be much easier to diagnose the problem.